# Is this a secure way of converting an array of 8 8bit integers into 1 64bit integer

Tags: python, binary, integer

I am handling arrays of 8bit integers that looks like this:

```
ph0 = [[255, 0, 65, 165, 23, 32, 198, 43]]
```

I want to convert the array into an integer such that the binary representation of the elements in the array concatenated will match that of the integer.

So using the above example, its binary representation will be:

```
['0b11111111', '0b00000000', '0b01000001', '0b10100101', '0b00010111', '0b00100000', '0b11000110', '0b00101011']
```

In the end I want an integer whose binary representation will be all of those binary values concatenated together. Like this:

```
0b1111111100000000010000011010010100010111001000001100011000101011
```

This is what I have come up with:

```
def convertArrayToInt(hashArr):
    val = 0
    for i in range(len(hashArr[0])-1, -1, -1):
        val += (hashArr[0][i])*2**((7-i)*8)
    return val
```

I can faithfully assume that each slot does not exceed 255 (hence do not need to worry about a slot occupying more than 8 bits).

Is my implementation safe to use? Are there any better ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a list of `int` objects. But this can be simply accomplished using:

```
int.from_bytes(bytes([255, 0, 65, 165, 23, 32, 198, 43]), 'big')
```